# Рентген-эндоваскулярный или Рентгенэндоваскулярный?

Tags: выбор-слов

Рентген-эндоваскулярный или Рентгенэндоваскулярный? Рентген-кабинет с дефисом, по идее должно все писаться с дефисом, начиная с рентген-...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можно предположить, что **специалисты пишут это слово через дефис.** Почему? При слитном написании его трудно прочесть, а это обязательно надо учитывать, например: Зав. отделением ***рентген-эндоваскулярной хирургии*** СПб ГБУЗ «Городская Мариинская больница».

https://rusendo.ru/ru/archive/theses-ru/25-2014/endoskopiya-zheludka/63-rentgen-endovaskulyarnye-vmeshatelstva-pri-zheludochno-kishechnykh-krovotecheniyakh.html

2. **Проблема в том, как объяснить это по правилам.**

**РЕНТГЕН**, м.1. Разг. =Рентгеновские лучи. Лечение рентгеном.  Назначить больного на р. Р. показал изменение костной ткани. 2. Разг. Аппарат для просвечивания этими лучами. Включить р. Поломка рентгена. По имени немецкого физика В.К. Рентгена (1845 - 1923).

Мы видим **пометку (разг.).** Поэтому есть два варианта – считать слово «рентген» (1) существительным или (2) иноязычным элементом. Но в обоих случаях грамматику сложного прилагательного с дефисным написанием **трудно объяснить** – такое образование нехарактерно для языка, а дефис используется, если есть соответствующее существительное: *юго-запад – юго-западный, контр-адмирал – контр-адмиральский.* У нас же такого существительного нет.

3. Тогда вспомним правила образования  **сложных существительных**

(1) Выбор  слитного написания  (образование нового слова с помощью иноязычного элемента): блицтурнир, аквапарк.

(2) Выбор дефисного написания (иноязычный элемент является приложением); арт-дизайн,  гала-представление.

4. **Распространяем это правило на прилагательные:** эндоваскулярный – рентген- эндоваскулярный.

Почему? Из определения видно, что это **одно из направлений** эндоваскулярной хирургии в целом, то есть **«приложение».**

***Эндоваскуля́рная хирурги́я*** (рентгенохирургия, интервенционная кардиология и интервенционная радиология) — хирургические вмешательства, проводимые на кровеносных сосудах чрескожным доступом под контролем методов лучевой визуализации с использованием специальных инструментов.

Answer (score 2):

Поиск по научным работам показывает, что [слитное написание](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&q=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&hl=ru&as_sdt=0,5) используется примерно в десять раз чаще, чем [дефисное](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=ru&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&btnG=). Такая пропорция обычно говорит о том, что в профессиональном узусе дефисное написание считается ошибочным. Кроме того, бросается в глаза, что статьи с дефисным написанием зачастую написаны не чисто русскоязычными авторами.

Впрочем, такой же поиск по аналогичному слову **рентген-хирургический**, дефисное написание которого зафиксировано в словаре Лопатина, даёт пропорции 1:100 в пользу ошибочного (слитного) написания. Рискну предположить, что в будущем и здесь предстоит нелёгкая борьба научного узуса с кодификаторами.

Замечу также, что среди словарных прилагательных есть и "слитные": *рентгеннегативный* и *рентгенпозтивный*.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ (обобщение темы)

**Как правильно выбрать форму письма**

1. Попробуем сравнить  две формы письма при наличии  и при отсутствии соединительной гласной: ***рентгенОхирургический*** и ***рентген-хирургический***. Мы видим, что при слитном написании  желательна **соединительная гласная**, которая становится как бы  «разделительной» и помогает прочитать и понять слово.

Если ее нет, то пишется  **дефис**, выполняя ту же функцию разделителя, и такое слово  читается легче. Здесь я вполне понимаю решение, данное в словаре Лопатина. А чем длиннее слово, тем **более обоснованным** становится выбор дефиса.

2. Здесь интересно вспомнить  **сложносокращенные слова**, которые обычно пишутся слитно.  Но ведь существует и дефисное написание: ***компакт-кассета, яхт-клуб,  конференц-зал, социал-демократ.*** Как это объяснить? Я полагаю, что  причина здесь аналогичная: слитное письмо затрудняет понимание слова.
3. **Разумность** – вот что должно лежать в основе любого решения, и разумность должна **противостоять формализму** и желанию «всех постричь одинаково». Если есть основное правило, то должны быть и исключения, и тогда приходится принимать **нестандартное, но разумное** решение.

Допустим, что специалисты пишут слитно: ***рентгенэндоваскулярный***. А почему они так пишут – вот что было бы интересно узнать от самих специалистов. Если по правилам, то по каким?  Если по значению, то что имеется в виду?

Мне кажется, что для обычных пользователей такая форма письма **совершенно неприемлема:**  если хотя бы с третьего рассказа слово еще можно прочесть, то буква Э на месте соединительной гласной  напрягает зрительное восприятие постоянно.

Допустим, специалисты привыкли  к такой форме, но  тогда  должна существовать **«специальная»  орфография**, как существует специальная лексика.

Так что непонятно, кто и с кем (или с чем) борется.

Comment: *непонятно, кто и с кем (или с чем) борется* — если действительно интересно, посмотрите [эту книгу](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/ortho/Beshenkova_Ivanova-2018-aspektnoje_opisanije.pdf). Там можно найти также немало примеров, когда узус побеждал кодификаторов.

Comment: Спасибо, оглавление интересное, так что прочту.  Вообще-то я обычно за узус, но здесь поддерживаю мнение Лопатина (если это он кодификатор). В общем случае пользователи интуитивно могут чувствовать более правильную форму, а  специалисты в области правописания должны уметь объяснить ситуацию.  А вот как ориентируются в ней специалисты-медики – мне не очень ясно.  То ли правило какое нашли, то ли  у них есть  какая-то  смысловая аргументация.  Чья позиция более прогрессивная.