# На каком основании после «рентген» ставят дефис? Например: «рентген-кабинет», «рентген-аппарат» и т. п

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, слитно-дефис

Размышляя над вопросом [Рентген-эндоваскулярный или Рентгенэндоваскулярный?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467361/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), я задумался: «А почему вообще ставится дефис в словах: *„рентген-кабинет“*, *„рентген-аппарат“* и т. п.?»

[Gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-) рекомендует такое написание в своих ответах:

> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правильно: рентген-кабинет, рентген-лаборант.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Верно дефисное написание: рентген-оборудование.

Но такое написание не подпадает ни под одно правило русского языка. Это что, какая-то укоренившаяся ошибка?

*«Рентген-кабинет»* — это сложносокращённое слово от *«рентгеновский кабинет»*, а *«рентген-аппарат»* — от *«рентгеновский аппарат»* и т. д.

По правилам русского языка сложносокращённые слова пишутся слитно, например: *«стоматологический кабинет»* — *«стоматкабинет»*.

*«Рентгеновский кабинет»* должен писаться в сложносокращённом виде *«рентгенкабинет»*, *«рентгеновский аппарат»* — *«рентгенаппарат»* и т. д. Если посчитать такие слова сложными, то: *«рентген**о**кабинет»*, *«рентген**о**аппарат»* и т. д.

Но дефис откуда?

Возможно, те, кто так пишут, руководствуются правилом:

> Б) Пишутся через дефис:
>
> 1. сложные существительные, образованные без соединительной гласной, каждая часть которых может употребляться как самостоятельное слово;
>
>    ```
>    Диван-кровать, кафе-закусочная, купля-продажа, генерал-полковник, премьер-министр, член-корреспондент, плащ-палатка, дизель-мотор, мотор-генератор, инженер-капитан, динамо-машина, стоп-кран, кран-балка, пила-рыба, лорд-канцлер.
>    ```
>
> *[[licey.net](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/657-214_slitnoe_i_defisnoe_napisanie_slozhnyh_slov.html)]*

Однако самостоятельного слова «рентген» в литературном русском языке нет, кроме фамилии изобретателя рентгеновских лучей *Вильгельма Конрада Рёнтгена*.

> **РЕНТГЕ́Н**, -а, м.
>
> 1. ***Разг.*** То же, что рентгеновские лучи (см. рентгеновский). *Перед просмотром рентгеном сестра Ивановская сняла толстую пропитанную кровью повязку с головы лейтенанта.* Емельянова, Хирург. || Просвечивание этими лучами. — *Рентген показал изменение костной ткани в области шестого грудного позвонка.* Коптяева, Иван Иванович.
> 2. ***Разг.*** Аппарат для просвечивания этими лучами.
> 3. *Спец.* Внесистемная единица измерения рентгеновского и гамма-излучений.
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

*«Рентген»* — это разговорное слово, т. е. просторечие, которым называют сами рентгеновские лучи или просвечивание ими.

Если кому-то не нравится приведённый словарь, вот ссылка на [БТС](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD&all=x), там точно так же слово *«рентген»* дано как разговорное.

Таким образом, нельзя писать *«рентген-кабинет»* через дефис, основываясь на том, что есть самостоятельное слово *«рентген»*.

---

Почему же так пишут? Да ещё и внесли в [орфографический словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Рентген-кабинет**.  При выборе дефиса в этом случае можно ориентироваться на три правила.

1. Рентген — самостоятельное **существительное,** хотя эта форма считается разговорной. Тогда это дефисное написание двух нарицательных существительных (вакуум-аппарат, динамо-машина).
2. Рентген-кабинет — это **сложносокращенное** слово, но дефисное написание возможно и в этих случаях (*компакт-кассета, яхт-клуб, конференц-зал*).
3. Рентген — это **иноязычный элемент** в роли приложения (рентгеновский кабинет), и это дефисное написание (арт-дизайн, гала-представление).

Также эти темы разбираются  в вопросе [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467361/Рентген-эндоваскулярный-или-Рентгенэндоваскулярный](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467361/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. По первому пункту: внесение сочетания через дефис с разговорным словом в орфографические словари выглядит нелогичным, если только это не объясняется проблемами с логикой у составителей словарей. По второму пункту: к сожалению, нет ссылок на источники правила, мне нужно время, чтоб разобраться. По третьему пункту: иноязычный элемент с какого языка?

Comment: 1) Не стоит  придавать такого принципиального значения стилевой пометке. Это общеизвестное слово. В форме существительного оно используется только в разговорной речи, но это не относится к сложным словам, в структуру которых оно входит.  2) Ссылок нет, но есть слова, а это факт, который сложно обойти. Запись выглядит корректной и удобной для понимании, аэто главное. 3) Большинство таких формантов из латинского или греческого языка, но они активно применяются во многих языках.

Comment: У Розенталя они перечислены  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=48#pp48  Обычно пишутся слитно, так как используются для образования новых слов. Но иногда имеют определительное значение (функция приложения), тогда мы пишем дефис. Таких слов тоже немало: арт, альфа, вице, гала,  экстра и др.